# Angular 2 reuse the same route on reload

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to use the same route, if I reload the page (F5) or open it into a new tab.

As example I use following route:

```
http://localhost:4200/show-category/-KmhdoAJO0WQbTzS9gll
```

If I press F5 this is the result:

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

the problem is that it shows the same component as before but because of the missing id there are no values. The app crashes.

(I sat a few hours on another problem, maybe I am now not concentrated enough to find the error.)

I hope there's a person which can help me very quickly.

```
const appRoutes: Routes =  [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'access-denied', component: AccessDeniedComponent },
  { path: 'add-category', component: AddCategoryComponent },
  { path: 'add-reply/:id', component: AddReplyComponent },
  { path: 'add-topic/:id', component: AddTopicComponent },
  { path: 'change-user-roles', component: ChangeUserRolesComponent },
  { path: 'edit-category/:id', component: EditCategoryComponent },
  { path: 'edit-reply/:id', component: EditReplyComponent },
  { path: 'edit-topic/:id', component: EditTopicComponent },
  { path: 'delete-category/:id', component: DeleteCategoryComponent },
  { path: 'delete-reply/:id', component: DeleteReplyComponent },
  { path: 'delete-topic/:id', component: DeleteTopicComponent },
  { path: 'register-user', component: RegisterUserComponent },
  { path: 'show-category/:id', component: ShowCategoryComponent },
  { path: 'show-topic/:id', component: ShowTopicComponent },
  { path: 'user-profile', component: UserProfileComponent },
]
```

Comment: What you want is the default behavior. It's difficult to tell why it's not working  for you. Please provide more information. For example the routes configuration.

Comment: This is a default behavior. You should subscribe to the `params` observable to fetch the `id` parameters.